# cygwin bash: unexpected EOF

Tags: bash, cygwin

What is the problem with the following bash code ?

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 {file}"
fi
```

Generates an error of "Unexpected EOF".
Cygwin 2.10.0(0.325/5/3) in Windows 10.

Comment: Do you have DOS carriage returns in the file, in particular immediately adjacent to `then`?

Comment: That was the problem. After 36 years of programming you still learn every day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have DOS line endings in your file, which means the `bash` parser sees

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then\r
  echo "Usage: $0 {file}"\r
fi\r
```

Rather than a complete `if` statement, it sees the beginning of one, one whose condition consists of (so far) the commands `[ -z "$1" ]`, `then\r`, `echo "Usage: $0 {file}"\r`, and `fi\r`. The parser is still looking for the `then` keyword to terminate the condition list, but finds the end of the file instead.

Save your script as a POSIX text file using `\n` as the line endings, not `\r\n`.